# Get output from mysql query file source

Tags: mysql

Can I retrieve output from mysql for the querys inside the file `query.sql` after the import?

```
mysql --host=localhost --user="root" --password="123456" --database=mytest --execute="SOURCE /var/www/test/WebService/public/tmp/querys.sql"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect the input of `mysql` to the file. To get the information messages like `1 row inserted`, add the `--verbose` option.

```sh
mysql --verbose --host=localhost --user="root" --password="123456" --database=mytest < /var/www/test/WebService/public/tmp/querys.sql
```

You can get more messages by using multiple `--verbose` options.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I have tried --verbose but it return only the query string, but not the result.

Comment: Did you try `--verbose --verbose`?

Comment: Thanks you so much, `--verbose` `--verbose`  works! I didn't read correctly first time, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to copy or append the output of the query to a file then you can use the `--tee=file_name` command line option. See [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) to know more on the same.

Comment: I need the output for every query inside the file (something like phpmyadmin). For example I want to see "1 row inserted" or "error update" but I don't know if this is possible